# Java Swing dynamic grid

Tags: java, swing, layout, icons, jbutton

I'm doing a java game swing-based, in which players in their turn add a tile to the ground next to those already present, so i need a particular gridLayout that let me to build a dinamic grid.

The tile is a (image) button;
So, the start tile is in position 0,0, the first player can choose eight different moves, and so on, any ideas? GridBagConstraints doesn't accept negative value, is right?

i'm trying without a Layout, with absolute coordinates, I can think of other solutions less raw...

Comment: *"he start tile is in position 0,0, the first player can choose eight different moves, and so on"*  Huh?  If the next move needs to be adjacent to the tile at 0,0 (top left) of the grid, aren't there only **3** tiles adjacent to that corner tile?  Does the playing field 'wrap around?'

Answer (score 2):

You might get some ideas from this [game](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/buttons) that uses a `GridLayout` of `JToggleButton`. Each button uses its *selected* state to decide which Unicode glyph to show, but an `Icon` would work as well.

Comment: @trahsgod this layout seems static, mine is dinamic... but i'll give a look

Comment: See `enum Game`, used by `resetGame()` to effect a dynamic layout.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a hash table keyed by pairs of integers.

Comment: sorry, i don't understand your answer;what i need is a way to visualize the buttons, not a data structure...

Comment: @Andrew yes! it wrap around i forgot to say that, but 8 position it means that